# how to get sales rank from Amazon ItemSearch/ItemLookup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to grab sales ranks from the Amazon product advertising API. I'm using the [amazon_product](http://code.papercavalier.com/amazon_product/) gem.

```
request = AmazonProduct["us"]

request.configure do |c|
  c.key    = AMAZON_KEY
  c.secret = AMAZON_SECRET
  c.tag    = TAG
end

#itemlookup
response = request.find('B003XU6H8I', :response_group => 'SalesRank')
response.find('Item').first
=> {"ASIN"=>"B003XU6H8I"}
```

Why does the API return no sales rank for this item? Also, I've tried getting the SalesRank response group with an item search but they don't get returned. Is this a problem with the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sales rank is most likely not available.  I have done several things with Amazon, and when they don't have what I'm looking for, I usually scrape it.

i.e. - in code, browse to the specific product you want and scrape the information from Amazon.  Browse to http://www.amazon.com/dp/[ASIN] and under product details you can parse out the rank(s).  In code, replacing the [ASIN] with others from the list of products you need.

I've used libraries like selenium and watir or watin, to easily scrape specific information I needed.

Answer (score 6):

I would just scrape this with Nokogiri.

For example, enter the following in irb to see:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
website = 'http://www.amazon.com/dp/B000YYODLO'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(website))
puts doc.css('#SalesRank').text[/\#.*\)/]
```

Of course, you will need to change the B000YYODLO to whatever the ASIN is of whatever you are scraping for. Unless you are looking for the sales rank of a coffee press, in which case I answered two questions at once.

Also, the CSS selector #SalesRank pulls out the whole line, you can use regex like I did to parse out whatever you need.

Also, since I am not familiar with the api you are using you may want to look through it to see if they are using css selectors because you may just need to change SalesRank to #SalesRank.

I hope this helps.